# What is the best way to parse double from unknown culture in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double

I'm using XML files to store user data. Files may be saved and loaded from different localisation. Depending on the culture, a double number can be saved as "1.2345" or as "1,2345". The difference is the decimal separator.

Currently I'm using the following code for parsing:

```
private double StringToDouble(string input)
{
    string decimalPoint = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;

    if (!input.Contains(decimalPoint))
    {
        input = input.Replace(".", decimalPoint);
        input = input.Replace(",", decimalPoint);
    }

    return double.Parse(input);
}
```

The code above works well, but obviously it is not the best.
Can you offer a better solution?

Comment: Are thousands separators something you need to worry about? (i.e. a space versus a comma), or will they all < 1000 with a decimal?

Comment: For now no problem with the thousands separator.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I can add to the existing answers.  But I would recommend scrubbing your inputs as a separate step from parsing/processing.  (Separation of concerns.)  If you find other non-conforming information, you can add it to your scrubbing filter. If you reach a point where it's no longer necessary, you can remove it from the filter. In either case you won't have to touch your core business logic.  

But of course you have to balance this against the added complexity, performance concerns, etc.

Comment: One other advantage of scrubbing: `ParseExact()` is usually orders of magnitude faster than `Parse()` ... but of course it requires your data to be in a canonical format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I don't think your current solution is too bad. It isn't elegant, but you are given non-elegant data. As others have suggested, I would see if it is possible to get the XML files in a consistent format, or *at least* have the XML files saved with a culture info:

```xml
<yourRootElement xml:lang="en-US">
```

That way you won't have to guess.

Barring that, you could also do something like this:

```
private double StringToDouble(string input)
{
    var last = input.LastIndexOfAny(new[] {',', '.'});
    var separator = last >= 0 ? input[last] : '.';
    var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = separator.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return double.Parse(input, clone);
}
```

`CultureInfo.Clone` is expensive, but you can cache culture info based on what the separator is. This also gives you the flexibility to set up different thousands separators, if needed. You would have to assume what the thousands separator is depending on the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add a culture record in my XMLs. Is it better to double.TryParse first. If not success, to clone and store customized CultureInfo (as you proposed) for all the next double.TryParse.

Answer (score 2):

If you serialize your double to your xml file as a double primitive and not as a string, it will save it with "." so you can parse it with invariant culture.

If it's saved as text, you can try something like this:

```
double result = double.Parse(input.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that you can still have problems with thousands separators in numbers like "1.234.567,89".

Comment: Also agree with you, but some data comes from third party software in their own format.

Comment: Thank you. The code works. I didn't know that CultureInfo.InvariantCulture assumes "." as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to save numbers in a fixed fformat, i.e. with fixed decimal separator. This means that transformation from the user's culture to the culture in which number must be saved should be performed.

Comment: I agree, but some of the files come from a third party software (forex platforms) that save quotation in their own format.