# How to figure out if user entered in the format 5,3 then I need to convert it to 5.3 and vice verca and then perform the calculation.in dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Currently my mobile application which has both German and English language selection. The problem is the calculation part.
The German system uses "," as a separator (for e.g 2,53) where as English system uses dot as separator (for e.g 2.53) for decimal number system.

```
                QuiescentConsumption = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Question == Constants.QuiescentConsumption)?.Answer,
                AlarmCurrentMeasured = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Question == Constants.AlarmCurrentMeasured)?.Answer,
                AlarmCurrentConsumption = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Question == Constants.AlarmCurrentConsumption)?.Answer,
                FaultCurrentMeasured = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Question == Constants.FaultCurrentMeasured)?.Answer,
                FaultCurrentConsumption = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Question == Constants.FaultCurrentConsumption)?.Answer,
```

I have above fields. Now I want to find if user enters comma(,) then i want to replace it to dot(.) How can this be implemented in .net in LINQ?

**QuiescentConsumption, AlarmCurrentMeasured, AlarmCurrentConsumption, FaultCurrentMeasured, FaultCurrentConsumption will have the values stored which user entered. I want to figure out if user entered in the format 5,3 then I need to convert it to 5.3 and vice verca and then perform the calculation. Is there any way to implement this?**

Comment: Your calculations and numbers should be in a numeric format. Convert early

Comment: @TheGeneral : Could you please explain

Comment: it's not clear, which is your string based input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to parse double from unknown culture in .NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612982/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-double-from-unknown-culture-in-net-c)

Comment: Does your input accept values over 999? If so, there will be no way to distinguish between the thousands separator and the decimal separator. E.g. 1,000 would be one thousand in american format and 1 in german format.

Answer (score 0):

convert from string (input) to double early!

```
string a = "2,13";
string b = "2.13";

NumberFormatInfo formatGER = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatGER.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
formatGER.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

var formatENG = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatENG.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
formatENG.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

var a1 = double.Parse(a, formatGER);
var b1 = double.Parse(b, formatENG);

Console.WriteLine(a1*3.14);
Console.WriteLine(b1*3.14);
```

gives you:
6,6882
6,6882

Comment: QuiescentConsumption, AlarmCurrentMeasured, AlarmCurrentConsumption, FaultCurrentMeasured, FaultCurrentConsumption will have the values stored which user entered. I want to figure out if user entered in the format 5,3 then I need to convert it to 5.3 and vice verca and then perform the calculation. Is there any way to implement this?